# Conectar con IMAPS a un buzón de correo compartido mediante JavaMail

Tags: java

Buenas,

Estoy intentado realizar una conexión a un buzón de correo compartido mediante API java mail (Versión 1.5.5).

La forma que he visto en la que se tiene que realizar este tipo de conexión es:

```
props.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.host", "HOST_IMAP");
props.put("mail.imaps.port", 993);

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
_store = session.getStore("imaps");
_store.connect("DOMINIO\\USUARIO\\CUENTACOMPARTIDA","PASS");
Folder inbox = _store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Al intentar realizar la conexión en _store.connect me retorna:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.

at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:684)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
```

Mi usuario tiene permisos en la buzón compartido, ya que he podido acceder sin problemas mediante Outlook. Además, tengo instalados los certificados SSL.
Por lo que me planteo si la cadena de connect es correcta.

¿Se tiene que realizar la conexión a buzones compartidos de otra forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución al problema.

La solución implica enviar las credenciales mediante el properties que se añade al `getInstance` de la session y realizar la conexión `_store.connect` sin parámetros.

Por lo que el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
props.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.host", "HOST_IMAP");
props.put("mail.imaps.port", 993);
props.put("mail.user","DOMINIO\\USUARIO\\CUENTACOMPARTIDA");
props.put("mail.password","password");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
_store = session.getStore("imaps");
_store.connect();
Folder inbox = _store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```